# getting rid of unnecessary parenthesis

Tags: haskell, coding-style, parentheses

I wrote a function for evaluating a polynomial at a given number. The polynomial is represented as a list of coefficients (e.g. `[1,2,3]` corresponds to `x^2+2x+3`).

```
polyEval x p = sum (zipWith (*) (iterate (*x) 1) (reverse p))
```

As you can see, I first used a lot of parenthesis to group which expressions should be evaluated. For better readability I tried to eliminate as many parenthesis using `.` and `$`. (In my opinion more than two pairs of nested parenthesis are making the code more and more difficult to read.) I know that function application has highest priority and is left associative. The `.` and `$`are both right associative but `.` has priority 9, while `$` has priority 0.

So it seemed to me that following expression cannot be written with even fewer parenthesis

```
polyEval x p = sum $ zipWith (*) (iterate (*x) 1) $ reverse p
```

I know that we need parenthesis for `(*)` and `(*x)` to convert them to prefix functions, but is it possible to somehow remove the parenthesis around `iterate (*x) 1`?

Also what version would you prefer for readability?

I know that there are many other ways to achieve the same, but I'd like to discuss my particular example, as it has a function evaluated in two arguments  `(iterate (*x) 1)` as middle argument of another function that takes three arguments.

Comment: I'd prefer a fold for readability. By the way, this can be done point free: `polyEval' x = foldl' (\b a -> a + x*b) 0`.

Comment: @Alec I just updated my question: I constructed this particular example because of the particular case where you have a function evaluated in two arguments as an argument for another one, and want to discuss this particular example. (by the way: your function is not entirely point free as you are explicitly using arguments for your lambda)

Comment: Assuming one keeps the code structure as it is, I think `... where powers = iterate (*x) 1` would help. I'd use `polyEval x = sum . zipWith (*) powers . reverse`

Answer (score 3):

As usual with this sort of question I prefer the OP's version to any of the alternatives that have been proposed so far. I would write

```
polyEval x p = sum $ zipWith (*) (iterate (* x) 1) (reverse p)
```

and leave it at that. The two arguments of `zipWith (*)` play symmetric roles in the same way that the two arguments of `*` do, so eta-reducing is just obfuscation.

The value of `$` is that it makes the outermost structure of the computation clear: the evaluation of a polynomial at a point is the sum of something. Eliminating parentheses should not be a goal in itself.

Answer (score 2):

So it might be a little puerile, but I actually really like to think of Haskell’s rules in terms of food. I think of Haskell’s left-associative function application `f x y = (f x) y` as a sort of *aggressive nom* or *greedy nom*, in that the function `f` refuses to wait for the `y` to come around and immediately eats the `f`, unless you take the time to put these things in parentheses to make a sort of "argument sandwich" `f (x y)` (at which point the `x`, being uneaten, becomes hungry and eats the `y`.) The only boundaries are the operators and the special forms.

Then within the boundaries of the special forms, the operators consume whatever is around them; finally the special forms take their time to digest the expressions around them. This is the only reason that `.` and `$` are able to save some parentheses.

Finally this we can see that `iterate (* x) 1` is probably going to *need to be in a sandwich* because we don't want something to just eat `iterate` and stop. So there is no great way to do that without changing that code, unless we can somehow do away with the third argument to `zipWith` -- but that argument contains a `p` so that requires writing something to be more point-free.

So, one solution is to change your approach! It makes a little more sense to store a polynomial as a list of coefficients in the already-reversed direction, so that your `x^2 + 2 * x + 3` example is stored as `[3, 2, 1]`. Then we don't need to perform this complicated `reverse` operation. It also makes the mathematics a little simpler as the product of two polynomials can be rewritten recursively as `(a + x * P(x)) * (b + x * Q(x))` which gives the straightforward algorithm:

```hs
 newtype Poly f = Poly [f] deriving (Eq, Show)

 instance Num f => Num (Poly f) where
     fromInteger n = Poly [fromInteger n]
     negate (Poly ps) = Poly (map negate ps)
     Poly f + Poly g = Poly $ summing f g where
         summing [] g = g
         summing f [] = f
         summing (x:xs) (y:ys) = (x + y) : summing xs ys
     Poly (x : xs) * Poly (y : ys) = prefix (x*y) (y_p + x_q) + r where
         y_p = Poly $ map (y *) xs
         x_q = Poly $ map (x *) ys
         prefix n (Poly m) = Poly (n : m)
         r = prefix 0 . prefix 0 $ Poly xs * Poly ys
```

Then your function

```hs
evaluatePoly :: Num f => Poly f -> f -> f
evaluatePoly (Poly p) x = eval p where
    eval = (sum .) . zipWith (*) $ iterate (x *) 1
```

lacks parentheses around `iterate` because the `eval` is written in pointfree style, so `$` can be used to consume the rest of the expression. As you can see it unfortunately leaves some new parentheses around `(sum .)` to do this, though, so it might not be totally worth your while. I find the latter less readable than, say,

```hs
evaluatePoly (Poly coeffs) x = sum $ zipWith (*) powersOfX coeffs where
    powersOfX = iterate (x *) 1
```

I might even prefer to write the latter, if performance on high powers is not super-critical, as `powersOfX = [x^n | n <- [0..]]` or `powersOfX = map (x^) [0..]`, but I think `iterate` is not too hard to understand in general.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps breaking it down to more elementary functions will simplify further.  First define a dot product function to multiply two arrays (inner product).

```
dot x y = sum $ zipWith (*) x y
```

and change the order of terms in polyEval to minimize the parenthesis

```
polyEval x p = dot (reverse p) $ iterate (* x) 1
```

reduced to 3 pairs of parenthesis.